# Is there a way to shuffle (not sort) a list in python which can be reversed?

Tags: python, list, reverse, shuffle

Is there a way where we can shuffle a list in python and reverse it if we needed
for eg `a = [1,2,3,4,'a','b','D','#']` and make it as `4aD#1b23` random which can be later reversed as it was in the list like `[1,2,3,4,'a','b','D','#']`

I tried to make a reference number which will be used to reverse it but not got any exact solution for it you have please let me know.

Comment: just use shuffle method from the random library:
`from random import shuffle
shuffle(list)
print(list)`

Comment: but using it cannot be reversed i want to know method to reverse the list after shuffle

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you want to use for this? Is there a reason you can't simply copy the original list?

Comment: This seems a bit like an XY problem to me, and depending on the context there may be different good solutions, e.g. just keeping a copy of the original list, or shuffling and later sorting `(index, item)` pairs generated with `enumerate`, or recreating the original order based on some heuristic (e.g. "first sorted numbers, then sorted strings"), or something entirely different.

Comment: Maybe you want to identify a randomly-chosen permutation of N items?

Comment: Might be useful [How do I un-shuffle a list back to its original form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57341086/12575557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a shuffle function yourself using the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for example, in which case you can use your own seeded random number generator. You can then implement another unshuffle algorithm using the same seeded RNG. I've adapted [my answer where I've done this previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24262147/476) to Python:

```
import random


def seeded_shuffle(l, seed):
    rng = random.Random(seed)
    for i in range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1):
        j = rng.randint(0, i)
        l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]


def seeded_unshuffle(l, seed):
    rng = random.Random(seed)
    indices = [rng.randint(0, i) for i in range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1)]

    for i, j in enumerate(indices[::-1]):
        l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b', 'D', '#']
seed = 42

seeded_shuffle(a, seed)
print(a)  # [4, 'a', 'D', '#', 3, 'b', 1, 2]

seeded_unshuffle(a, seed)
print(a)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b', 'D', '#']
```